# Show that $(2, 3+\sqrt{-61})$ and $(5, 3+\sqrt{-61})$ are invertible ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-61}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

So the question is that I have to show that $(2, 3+\sqrt{-61})$ and $(5, 3+\sqrt{-61})$ are invertible ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-61}]$ and to determine the order of their classes in Pic($\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-61}])$. 
So I know that the inverse of an ideal $I$ is $R:I=\{x\in K|xI\subset R\}$ where $K$ is the field of fraction of $R$, so $K=Q(R)$. But I don't know how to go about this in a smart way.

Comment: Not really to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring $R = \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-61}]$ is a Dedekind domain, as $-61\equiv 3 \mod 4$ implies it is the full ring of algebraic integers of $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{-61})$, so every nonzero fractional ideal of $K$ is invertible, including these two integral ideals. (But the inverses of these integral ideals are not going to be integral ideals, just fractional ones.)

The Picard group of $R$ is the ideal class group, i.e. the quotient group of all fractional ideals by principal ones. So you have to raise the ideal to powers until you find one that is principal.

For $I_1 = (2,3+\sqrt{-61})$ (obviously $I_1 \not = (1)$), it is easy:
$$I_1^2 = (2,1+\sqrt{-61}) (2,1-\sqrt{-61}) = (4, 2\pm 2\sqrt{-61}, 62) = (2).$$
The norm of an ideal divides the norms of all its elements, so for $I_2 = (a = 5, b = 3+\sqrt{-61})$ it must be either 5 or 1, which forbids it to be principal (why?). Then, the obvious "$R$-linear" basis $ \{a^2, ab, b^2\} $ of $I_2^2$ can be "simplified" via $\Bbb Z$-linear combinations to $ \{ 25, 8+\sqrt{-61} \} $. Then, as you can check using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/344920) argument, this set is also a $\Bbb Z$-basis of the ideal, and obviously there's no $\pm 5$ in $I_2^2$. Thus you should try the third power, and indeed there is an (even $\Bbb Z$-) linear combination of $ \{ a^3, a^2 b, ab^2, b^3 \} $ that has a norm of 125 (I found it using SageMath).

Comment: I don't get why for the calculation of $I_1^2$ you work with $(2, 1+\sqrt{-61}$ and its conjugate. Does it not need to be $(2, 3+\sqrt{-61})$? Also I don't see how the square is equal to (2). And why work with its conjugate when you want its square? I think I understand the rest of your answer so thank you!

Comment: That's a general observation: without changing the ideal, you can always 1) add other element (simpler-looking, or with smaller coefficients as here) to your generating set that is known to be in the ideal, and 2) remove a 'redundant' one that belongs in the '$R$-linear' span of the remaining elements.

Comment: The sets $A = \{ 2, 3+\sqrt{-61} \}$ and $B = \{ 2, 1+\sqrt{-61} \}$ generate the same ideal, as every element $b_j \in B$ can be represented as $a_1 r_{1j} + a_2 r_{2j}$ (where $r_{ij} \in R$), and vice versa. In this case $r_{ij}$ are integer, but you could've added e. g. $(3+\sqrt{-61})\sqrt{-61}$ if you needed it for some reason.

Comment: The square is equal to $(2)$ as $62-4\cdot 15 = 2 \in I_1^2$ and all generators are $R$-multiples of $2$. It just happened with the first ideal that a number and its conjugate can easily be found in it, the fact simplified calculations. For $I_2$ I couldn't easily find something similar (doesn't mean it can't be done), so not having a better plan I had to resort to a frontal attack.

Comment: So I guess that is why you square with the conjugate as well? And I still don't really see how $I_1^2=(2)$ Im sorry
Edit: Sorry was too soon lol